# How to vertically center a div on page when changing content?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I have a certain small text on the card which I was able to align center vertically.
But if you make the text big then everything deteriorates.

I made two options and they work independently of each other, but they do not work together. In the large text some of the text is lost.

**Important note:** Text should always be centered vertically.

```
.article-div{
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
    padding: 0px 40px 0px 40px;
    text-align: justify;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Big text: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/SmallSani/pen/JrjvJy)

```
.article-div{
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content:  center;
    padding: 0px 40px 0px 40px;
    text-align: justify;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Small text: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/SmallSani/pen/WZNJpV)

Thank you!

Comment: Both CodePen have same link.

Comment: No.  The links are different. Both show correct work for large and small text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to *wrap* the `flexbox`:

1. Remove `flex-wrap: wrap` from `article-div` (and therefore `align-content: center` which has meaning only when *wrapping*)
2. `article-div` is not a *flex item* (its parent `info-div` is not a `flexbox`), so `flex: 1 0 auto` can be removed.

See demo below with both the cases:

```css
.card-card {
  width: 1000px;
  min-width: 1000px;
  height: 560px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 50px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.card-img-div {
  width: 384px;
  height: 560px;
  position: relative;
}

.card-img {
  height: 560px;
  border-radius: 0px 0 0 0px;
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0px, 384px, 562px, 0px);
  left: -0px;
}

.info-div {
  width: 616px;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 0px 0px 0;
}

.caption-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.footer-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.article-div {
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  display: flex;
  /*flex: 1 0 auto;*/
  flex-direction: column;
  /*flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;*/
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0px 40px 0px 40px;
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-card">
  <div class="card-img-div">
    <img class="card-img" src="http://podsekai.in.ua/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/карась-серебряный.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="info-div">
    <div class="caption-div"></div>
    <div class="article-div">
<p>Карась — рыба семейства карповых, которая в нашей стране водится практически повсеместно. Это пресноводная рыба, которая может жить как в реках, так и в озерах со стоячей водой. Караси неприхотливы к условиям проживания и питанию, поэтому водятся практически в каждом водоеме.
</p>
<p>
Спинной плавник длинный<span lvl="3">, глоточные зубы однорядные</span>. Тело высокое с толстой спиной, умеренно сжатое с боков. Чешуя крупная и гладкая на ощупь. Окраска варьирует в зависимости от места обитания. 
  </p>
    </div>
      
    <div class="footer-div"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="card-card">
  <div class="card-img-div">
    <img class="card-img" src="http://podsekai.in.ua/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/карась-серебряный.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="info-div">
    <div class="caption-div"></div>
    <div class="article-div">
<p>Карась — рыба семейства карповых, которая в нашей стране водится практически повсеместно. Это пресноводная рыба, которая может жить как в реках, так и в озерах со стоячей водой. Караси неприхотливы к условиям проживания и питанию, поэтому водятся практически в каждом водоеме.
</p>
<p>
Спинной плавник длинный<span lvl="3">, глоточные зубы однорядные</span>. Тело высокое с толстой спиной, умеренно сжатое с боков. Чешуя крупная и гладкая на ощупь. Окраска варьирует в зависимости от места обитания. 
  </p>
<p>Карась — рыба семейства карповых, которая в нашей стране водится практически повсеместно. Это пресноводная рыба, которая может жить как в реках, так и в озерах со стоячей водой. Караси неприхотливы к условиям проживания и питанию, поэтому водятся практически в каждом водоеме.
</p>
<p>
Спинной плавник длинный<span lvl="3">, глоточные зубы однорядные</span>. Тело высокое с толстой спиной, умеренно сжатое с боков. Чешуя крупная и гладкая на ощупь. Окраска варьирует в зависимости от места обитания. 
  </p>
<p>Карась — рыба семейства карповых, которая в нашей стране водится практически повсеместно. Это пресноводная рыба, которая может жить как в реках, так и в озерах со стоячей водой. Караси неприхотливы к условиям проживания и питанию, поэтому водятся практически в каждом водоеме.
</p>
<p>
Спинной плавник длинный<span lvl="3">, глоточные зубы однорядные</span>. Тело высокое с толстой спиной, умеренно сжатое с боков. Чешуя крупная и гладкая на ощупь. Окраска варьирует в зависимости от места обитания. 
  </p>
<p>Карась — рыба семейства карповых, которая в нашей стране водится практически повсеместно. Это пресноводная рыба, которая может жить как в реках, так и в озерах со стоячей водой. Караси неприхотливы к условиям проживания и питанию, поэтому водятся практически в каждом водоеме.
</p>
<p>
Спинной плавник длинный<span lvl="3">, глоточные зубы однорядные</span>. Тело высокое с толстой спиной, умеренно сжатое с боков. Чешуя крупная и гладкая на ощупь. Окраска варьирует в зависимости от места обитания. 
  </p>      
    </div>
      
    <div class="footer-div"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

The above approach hides the top and bottom portion of the content when there is an overflow. Below is an approach using an *extra wrapper* that is *positioned absolutely* - check it out:

```css
.card-card {
  width: 1000px;
  min-width: 1000px;
  height: 560px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 50px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.card-img-div {
  width: 384px;
  height: 560px;
  position: relative;
}

.card-img {
  height: 560px;
  border-radius: 0px 0 0 0px;
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0px, 384px, 562px, 0px);
  left: -0px;
}

.info-div {
  width: 616px;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 0px 0px 0;
}

.caption-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.footer-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.article-div {
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  /*padding: 0px 40px 0px 40px;*/
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.article-div>div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  max-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-card">
  <div class="card-img-div">
    <img class="card-img" src="http://podsekai.in.ua/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/карась-серебряный.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="info-div">
    <div class="caption-div"></div>
    <div class="article-div">
      <div>
        <p>Карась — рыба семейства карповых, которая в нашей стране водится практически повсеместно. Это пресноводная рыба, которая может жить как в реках, так и в озерах со стоячей водой. Караси неприхотливы к условиям проживания и питанию, поэтому водятся
          практически в каждом водоеме.
        </p>
        <p>
          Спинной плавник длинный<span lvl="3">, глоточные зубы однорядные</span>. Тело высокое с толстой спиной, умеренно сжатое с боков. Чешуя крупная и гладкая на ощупь. Окраска варьирует в зависимости от места обитания.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer-div"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card-card">
  <div class="card-img-div">
    <img class="card-img" src="http://podsekai.in.ua/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/карась-серебряный.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="info-div">
    <div class="caption-div"></div>
    <div class="article-div">
      <div>
        <p>Карась — рыба семейства карповых, которая в нашей стране водится практически повсеместно. Это пресноводная рыба, которая может жить как в реках, так и в озерах со стоячей водой. Караси неприхотливы к условиям проживания и питанию, поэтому водятся
          практически в каждом водоеме.
        </p>
        <p>
          Спинной плавник длинный<span lvl="3">, глоточные зубы однорядные</span>. Тело высокое с толстой спиной, умеренно сжатое с боков. Чешуя крупная и гладкая на ощупь. Окраска варьирует в зависимости от места обитания.
        </p>
        <p>Карась — рыба семейства карповых, которая в нашей стране водится практически повсеместно. Это пресноводная рыба, которая может жить как в реках, так и в озерах со стоячей водой. Караси неприхотливы к условиям проживания и питанию, поэтому водятся
          практически в каждом водоеме.
        </p>
        <p>
          Спинной плавник длинный<span lvl="3">, глоточные зубы однорядные</span>. Тело высокое с толстой спиной, умеренно сжатое с боков. Чешуя крупная и гладкая на ощупь. Окраска варьирует в зависимости от места обитания.
        </p>
        <p>Карась — рыба семейства карповых, которая в нашей стране водится практически повсеместно. Это пресноводная рыба, которая может жить как в реках, так и в озерах со стоячей водой. Караси неприхотливы к условиям проживания и питанию, поэтому водятся
          практически в каждом водоеме.
        </p>
        <p>
          Спинной плавник длинный<span lvl="3">, глоточные зубы однорядные</span>. Тело высокое с толстой спиной, умеренно сжатое с боков. Чешуя крупная и гладкая на ощупь. Окраска варьирует в зависимости от места обитания.
        </p>
        <p>Карась — рыба семейства карповых, которая в нашей стране водится практически повсеместно. Это пресноводная рыба, которая может жить как в реках, так и в озерах со стоячей водой. Караси неприхотливы к условиям проживания и питанию, поэтому водятся
          практически в каждом водоеме.
        </p>
        <p>
          Спинной плавник длинный<span lvl="3">, глоточные зубы однорядные</span>. Тело высокое с толстой спиной, умеренно сжатое с боков. Чешуя крупная и гладкая на ощупь. Окраска варьирует в зависимости от места обитания.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer-div"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Look. On the big text the upper paragraph disappears.

Comment: With the addition of an additional layer everything began to work, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
.article-div{
   border:solid 1px red;
   height: calc(100% - 100px);
   display: flex;
   flex: 1 0 auto;
   flex-flow: column nowrap;
   align-content: center;
   justify-content:  center;
   padding: 0px 40px 0px 40px;
   text-align: justify;
   overflow: auto;
}
.article-div p{
   flex: 0 0 auto;  
}
```

[Small text Code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/veYjwb)

Comment: Look.  On the big text the upper paragraph disappears.

Comment: I don`t see any bug. All paragraph start from the begining from first till last. Overflow works fine. I use yandex browser v17.7.1.791 (last).

Comment: Vivaldi 1.11.917.43 (Stable channel)